# Unable to delete UDF

Tags: cassandra

I am using cassandra 3.10 and I am trying to delete two UDF which I had created: `cal_group_and_total` and `group_by_total`. `group_by_total` calls the former function so I first decided to delete the second function. And when I enter the following command:

`cqlsh>DROP FUNCTION group_by_total;`.

I get the following error:

`InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unconfigured function tec.group_by_total()"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) First check if function exist.

```
cqlsh> USE keyspace_name;

cqlsh> DESCRIBE FUNCTIONS;
```

2) If exist

```
cqlsh> DROP FUNCTION keyspace_name.group_by_total;
```